# Can I use Java applications to control Windows 7 functions?

Tags: java, api, windows-7

I'm relatively new to programming, I've been developing a lot lately in the eclipse environment and had the idea to build a small application for windows 7 that when I remove the power cord from my laptop it will enable my touch-pad and when the power is reconnected disable the touch-pad.

- My question is how exactly do I go about building such an application?

  - Is there a package I can import that gives me access to the Windows 7 API?
  - And is it possible to compile a java application so I can have it run at startup?

Comment: Java is not a good choice of language for getting into (viewing, using or changing) the specifics of the OS or hardware.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll look into the native language for windows applications. Do you have any personal preferences? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Andrew that java is probably not the best choice for such kind of application but anyway here is what you can do.

Java 7 file API is able to listen to file system. You should listen for the changes is root folder of your card. I guess you will get exception when card is disconnected.

Touch pad may be invoked as an external application. Take a look on this discussion for details: [Java - invoke on-screen keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281315/java-invoke-on-screen-keyboard)

Alternatively you can use JNI, JNA or one of java-to-windows libraries (JaWin, Jintegra, Jinterop). But I think this is much more complicated. I'd recommend you to start from the first solution.